# IPmenu alternatives

Tags: arm, raspberrypi

I really want to get IPmenu but I can't is there an alternative? I was having problems with the rasbian os since it has an arm architecture. Every time I try and install IPmenu it wants me to install objc 6 which I already installed the latest version. When I run

`ipmenu`

it gives me an error but the files does not exist. I don't completely understand why except for it uses ncurses.